# How are the SCAS and MOVS instructions affected by the value of the direction EFLAG?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32, string-operations, eflags

I want to know how setting or clearing the direction EFLAG changes how the SCAS and MOV instructions decrement or increment registers. I read some webpages and made the following assumptions I will list below.

I am using the MASM 32 SDK - no idea what version, I installed via Visual MASM's download and installation wizard - with Visual MASM to wright and MASM32 Editor to link and build them into objects and executables. I use a Windows 7 Pro 64 bit OS.

### SCAS

1. The SCAS instruction "compares a byte in AL or a word in AX with a byte or word pointed to by DI in ES." Therefore,to use SCAS, target string address must be moved to EDI and the string to find must be moved to the accumulator register (EAX and variants).
2. Setting direction flag then using SCAS will stop SCAS from running when using 32 bit systems. On 32 bit systems, it is impossible to force SCAS to "scan a string from the end to the start."
3. Any REP instruction always uses the ECX register as a counter and always decrements ECX regardless of the direction flag's value. This means it is impossible to "scan a string from the end to the beginning" using REP SCAS.

Sources:

[SCAS/SCASB/SCASW, Birla Institute of Technology and Science](https://sites.google.com/site/microprocessorsbits/string-instructions/scas-scasb-scasw)

[Scan String, from c9xm.me](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_287.html)

[SCAS/SCASB/SCASW/SCASD — Scan String, from felixcloutier.com](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/scas:scasb:scasw:scasd)

[MASM : Using 'String' Instructions, from www.dreamincode.net/forums](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/228774-masm-using-string-instructions/)

Below is part of the code from a program I will refer to in my questions:

```
;Generic settings from MASM32 editor 
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap: none

.data?
Input db 254 dup(?)
InputCopy db 254 dup(?)
InputLength dd ?, 0
InputEnd dd ?, 0

.data

.code

start:
push 254
push offset Input
call StdIn
mov InputLength, eax

;---Move Last Word---
lea esi, offset Input
sub esi, 4
lea edi, offset InputEnd
movw

;---Search section---
lea esi, Input
lea edi, InputCopy
movsb

mov ecx, InputLength
mov eax, 0
mov eax, "omit"

lea edi, offset InputEnd
repne scasw
jz close ;jump if a match was found and ZF was set to 1.
```

4. The code under the "Search" section  searches the string InputEnd 4 bytes at a time and thus 4 characters at a time. The block scans for the characters in EAX, i.e. the word "omit", ALWAYS beginning at the value of the memory address in edi then incrementing based on the suffix of SCAS (B, W, D, Q)[(MASM : Using 'String' Instructions, dream-in-code.com)](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/228774-masm-using-string-instructions/).

## MOVS

5. Using the "Move Last Word" section, I am able to get the last byte out of the string Input. I then used MOVSW to move just the last 4 bytes of the string Input to InputEnd, assuming the direction flag is clear. I must define Input as an array of bytes - `Input db 32 dup(?)` - for the block to work.
6. Regardless of how I define InputEnd (whether "dd ?, 0" or "db 12 dup(?)") mov and scas instructions' operation (flags set, registers modified etc.) will not change. The increment/decrement amount of SCAS and MOV are dependent on the suffix/last letter of the command, not the defined bytes or size of the pointers stored in EDI and ESI.
7. It is impossible to make MOVS transfer from the beginning to the end of a string. You must  the length of the string; load the corresponding addresses to EDI and ESI; Add the length of the string to the addresses stored at EDI and ESI; Last, set the direction flag using `std`. A danger here is targeting addresses below the source or destination bytes.
8. It is impossible to reverse a string's letters using MOVS since EDI and ESI are either **both decremented** or **both incremented** by MOVS.

Sources (asides from previously listed sites in SCAS section):

https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_203.html

http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/movsd.htm

Are these assumptions correct?
Is the x86 text on the sites' URLs a sign that the websites have wrong information?

Comment: _"I read some webpages"_. Why not just look it up in [Intel's manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) instead?

Comment: @Michael: or more simply, an HTML extract of the vol.2 manual like https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movs:movsb:movsw:movsd:movsq where you can find the Operation pseudocode for `movs`.  Actually the question already links the entry for SCAS so IDK what they're not understanding.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your updates.  What do you mean "*Is the x86 text on the sites' URLs a dire warning of being wrong?*" Intel's x86 manuals are rarely wrong.  The only problem I see in http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/movsd.htm is that the cycle timings are for some ancient CPU, and the code-size in bytes is wrong for `movsw`.  In 32-bit mode, `movsw` requires an operand-size prefix.  Just like `movsd` in 16-bit mode.  So the always-1-byte table is only right if you assume that only 16-bit code uses `movsw` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `repe/repne scas` and `cmps` aren't fast.  Also, the **"fast strings"** / ERMSB microcode for `rep movs` and `rep stos` **is only fast with DF=0** (normal / forward / increasing address).

`rep movs` with DF=1 is slow.  `repne scasw` is *always* slow.  They can be useful in the rare case where you're optimizing for code-size, though.

---

The documentation you linked sets out exactly how `movs` and `scas` are affected by DF.  **Read the Operation section in Intel's manuals.**

Note that it's always a post-increment/decrement so the first element compared doesn't depend on DF, only the updates to EDI and/or ESI.

Your code only depends on DF for the `repne scasw`.  It doesn't matter whether `movsb` increments (DF=0) or decrements (DF=1) EDI because you overwrite EDI before the next use.

---

**`repne scasw` is 16-bit "word" size using AX**, like it says in the HTML extracts of Intel's manual that you linked (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/scas:scasb:scasw:scasd).  That's both the increment *and* the compare width.

If you want overlapping dword compares of EAX, you can't use `scasw`.

You *could* use `scasd` in a loop, but then you'd have to decrement `edi` to create overlap.  So really you should just use a normal `cmp [edi], eax` and `add edi, 2` if you only want to check even positions.

(Or preferably use SSE2 SIMD `pcmpeqd` to implement `memmem` for a 4-byte search "needle".  Look at an optimized implementation like glibc's for ideas, or a strstr implementation but take out the checks for a `0` terminator in the "haystack".)

**`repne scasd` does *not* implement strstr or memmem**, it only searches for a single element.  With `byte` operand size, it implements `memchr`.

---

> On 32 bit systems, it is impossible to force SCAS to "scan a string from the end to the start."

`rep scas` doesn't operate on (implicit-length) C-style strings at all; it works on explicit-length strings.  Therefore you can just point EDI at the last element of the buffer.

Unlike `strrchr` you don't have to *find* the end of the string as well as the last match, you *know* / can calculate where the end of the string is.  Perhaps calling them "strings" is the problem; the x86 `rep`-string instructions actually work on known-size buffers.  That's why they take a count in ECX and don't also stop on a terminating `0` byte.

Use `lea edi, [buf + ecx - 1]` to set up for `std` ; `rep scasb`.  Or `lea edi, [buf + ecx*2 - 2]` to set up for backwards `rep scasw` on a buffer with ECX `word` elements.  (Generate a pointer to the last element = `buf + size - 1` = `buf-1 + size`)

> Any REP instruction always uses the ECX register as a counter and always decrements ECX regardless of the direction flag's value. This means it is impossible to "scan a string from the end to the beginning" using REP SCAS.

This just makes zero sense.  Of course it decrements; ECX=0 is how the search ends on no-match.  If want to calculate position relative to the end after searching from the end, you can do `length - ecx` or something like that.  Or do pointer-subtraction on EDI.

> 6: not the data type of registers stored in EDI and ESI.

Assembly language doesn't have types; that's a higher level concept.  It's up to you to do the right thing to the right bytes in asm.  EDI / ESI *are* registers; the pointers stored in them are just integers that have no type in asm.  You don't "store a register in EDI", it *is* a register.  Maybe you meant to say "pointer store in EDI"?  Registers don't have types; a bit-pattern (aka integer) in a register can be signed 2's complement, unsigned, a pointer, or whatever other interpretation you want.

But yes, **any magic that MASM does based on how you defined a symbol is completely gone once you have a pointer in a register.**

Remember that `movsd` is just a 1-byte instruction in x86 machine code, just the opcode.  It has only 3 inputs: DF, and two 32-bit integers in EDI and ESI, and they're all implicit (implied by the opcode byte).  There's no other context that can affect what the hardware does.  Every machine instruction has its documented effect on the architectural state of the machine; nothing more, nothing less.

> 7: It is impossible to make MOVS transfer from the beginning to the end of a string.  ...  `std`

No, `std` makes a transfer go backwards, from end to beginning.  `DF=0` is the normal / forward direction.  Calling conventions guarantee / require that DF=0 on entry and exit from any function so you don't need a `cld` before using string instructions; you can just assume that DF=0.  (And you should normally leave DF=0.)

> 8: It is impossible to reverse a string's letters using MOVS since EDI and ESI are either both decremented or both incremented by MOVS.

That's correct.  And a `lods` / `std` / `stos` / `cld` loop is not worth it vs. a normal loop that uses `dec` or `sub` on one of the pointers.  You can use `lods` for the read part and manually write backwards.  And you can go 4x faster by loading a dword and using `bswap` to reverse it in a register, so you're copying in chunks of 4 reversed bytes.

Or for in-place reversal: 2 loads into tmp regs, then 2 stores, then moves the pointers towards each other until they cross.  (Also works with `bswap` or `movbe`)

---

Other weird inefficiencies in your code:

```
    mov eax, 0                ;; completely pointless, EAX is overwritten by next instruction
    mov eax, "omit"
```

Also, `lea` with a `disp32` addressing mode is a pointless waste of code-size.  Only use LEA for static addresses in 64-bit code, for RIP-relative addressing.  Use `mov esi, OFFSET Input` instead, like you're doing with `push offset Input` earlier.

Comment: "Use lea edi, [buf + ecx] to set up for std ; rep scasb. Or lea edi, [buf + ecx*2] to set up for backwards rep scasw on a buffer with ECX word elements." Actually lea edi, [buf + ecx - 1] respectively lea edi, [buf + ecx * 2 - 2]. We want to point *at* the last element, not behind it.

Comment: @PeterCordes May I know a good source to learn and use these SSE SIMD instructions? I assume you are referring to "Intel Software and Services 2 SIMD Instructions." I plan to use this as an instructions reference:chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/https://www.intel.sg/content/dam/www/public/apac/xa/en/pdfs/ssg/Intel_Processor_Architecture_SIMD_Instructions.pdf

Comment: @JoachimRives:  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info has some links.  I learned from Agner Fog's optimization guide and from seeing examples (including compiler output, but also stuff like glibc's memset, strlen and strcpy functions)

Answer (score 0):

### Personal Subjective Summary of Answers

Here I will list the answers I feel that other users have given just for clarity. I will change this over time and select an answer in 1 week from August 8, 2019.

1. You can make SCAS scan from the "end" of a string.

> Use lea edi, [buf + ecx - 1] to set up for std ; rep scasb. Or lea
>   edi, [buf + ecx*2 - 2] to set up for backwards rep scasw on a buffer
>   with ECX  word elements. (Generate a point to the last element = buf +
>   size - 1 = buf-1  size)

Referring to the sample code in the question, I could write

```
lea edi, [Input + ecx - 1]
std
rep scasb
```

The second option

```
lea edi, [Input + ecx*2 - 2]
std
rep scasw
```

gives a backwards rep scasw on a buffer with ECX word elements.

2. If want to calculate position relative to the end after searching from the end,

   > you can do length - ecx or something like that. Or do
   >   pointer-subtraction on EDI.
3. Referring to registers and symbol definitions in MASM,

   > You don't "store a register in EDI", they are registers. Maybe you
   >   meant to say "pointer"? And yes, any magic that MASM does based on how
   >   you defined a symbol is completely gone once you have a pointer in a
   >   register. ASM doesn't have datatypes.
4. You can make std transfer backwards, from "end" to "beginning" of a string by setting the direction flag before musing mov.
5. Calling conventions guarantee / require that DF=0 on entry and exit from ANY function, so you don't need a `cld` before using string instructions.