# Very beginners question - constant value too large

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have a silly question... I am trying to do string comparisons and first, I want to `mov`e each string into a register. I first used `BYTE` to declare the strings, and realized that I mismatched the size of the register to the variable. In correcting this, I ran into `constant value too large`. From my understanding, I am trying to pack too many bits into a `DWORD` variable. However, what makes this strange to me is that I was using a smaller declaration first and had no issue with that... What am I doing wrong?

```
str1 DWORD "Hello World!", 0
str2 DWORD 20 DUP(0)
----------------------------------
mov eax, str2
mov ebx, str1
```

Note : `str2` is initialized the way it is for user input, my issue lies with `str1`

Comment: You can't move a string into a register.  You can move an individual *byte* of a string into a register, or you can move a *pointer* to the string.  Which is it that you want?

Comment: Normally you want BYTE / DB arrays for strings; MASM is weird about quoted multi-character strings as operands to DWORD, same as for `DD` in [When using the MOV mnemonic to load/copy a string to a memory register in MASM, are the characters stored in reverse order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57427904).  If you want the address in a register, use `mov eax, OFFSET str2`.  The pointer is always a dword, regardless of the element width of MASM variable's type.